# Get character inserted at <textarea> on keypress or keydown

Tags: textarea, keypress, keydown

I was wondering if there is a way to get the current value of a  on the keydown or the keypress event. To define "current value" in a better way, I mean, by this, the value of the textarea, including the "just inserted" character. By default on these events the  value does not change. If this is not possible i would like to know if there is a **cross browser** way to get the *just inserted* value of the key that I pressed (I don't need the keycode, because e.g. this does not define, supposing that I enter a characterm if the character entered is Uppercase or Lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait for the keyup event to fire before the actual value changes.

Otherwise, for keydown or keypress, you have to map the character code on the event (and this is different per browser unless you use some JS library like jQuery which standardizes it) and determine the cursor position and modify the value that way. This can get a little tricky especially around browser support unless you use a JS library to do this.

Comment: Yes. I know that. Actually that's why I asked about a cross-browser way to do that, because not all browsers capture characters on keydown or keypress.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module that translates `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events into characters and keys respectively. https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight

Example:

```
 textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var character = keysight(event).char
    if(character === 'w') {
        console.log("got lower case w")
    } else if(character === 'W') {
        console.log("got upper case w")
    }
 })
```